# How to Edit/Delete Data in MySQL database using servlet

Tags: mysql, database, servlets

if we are going to add new data in the db, we use something like this

```
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://mysql.cityu.edu.hk:3306/", "yyy", "xxx");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.execute("USE yyy");
            id = (String) request.getParameter("id");
            text = (String) request.getParameter("text");
            time = (String) request.getParameter("time");
            query="insert into Table values(0,'" + id + "', 'ABC' ,'" + text + "','" + time + "');";
            int rs = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

but how about if we are going to edit/delete something in the database? any tutorial? many thanks! cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at mysql manual for syntax of `update` and `delete`.

```
update table set column=value where id=rowID
delete from table where id=rowID
```